# Span of Infinite Vandermonde matrix?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

> Q1: Does there exist $x \in (0,1)^\mathbb{N}$ such that for any decreasing $v \in (0,1)^\mathbb{N}$ that converges to $0$ (meaning, $v_{n+1} < v_n$ and $v_n \rightarrow 0$), there is $a \in (0,1)^\mathbb{N}$ with:
>   $$
> \begin{array}{lll}
> \sum a_n & =& v_0\\
> \sum a_n x_n& = &v_1\\
> \sum a_n x^2_n & = &v_2\\
> \mbox{etc.}&&
> \end{array}
> $$

Equivalently, think of an *infinite* Vandermonde matrix with coefficients $x \in (0,1)^\mathbb{N}$
$$
V(x) = \left(
\begin{array}{llllll}
1      & 1    & 1      & \cdots & 1     & \cdots\\
x_1    & x_2  & x_3    & \cdots & x_n   & \cdots\\
x^2_1  & x^2_2& x^2_3  & \cdots & x^2_n & \cdots\\
\vdots &\vdots&\vdots  & \ddots &\vdots & \vdots\\
x_1^m & x^m_2 &x^m_3 & \cdots & x^m_n  & \cdots\\
\vdots &\vdots&\vdots  & \ddots &\vdots & \vdots 
\end{array}
\right)
$$
(where superscrits represent exponents and not just row position) and ask whether there is $x \in (0,1)^\mathbb{N}$ such that for any decreasing and convergent (to $0$) $v \in (0, 1)^\mathbb{N}$, there is $a \in (0, 1)^\mathbb{N}$ satisfying $V(x) \cdot a= v$.

Intuitively, $x$ cannot be chosen arbitrarily. I suspect that a positive answer requires $x$ to be such that $\{x_n \in (0,1) : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is dense in $(0,1)$.

As always, thank you all for your help.

Comment: Question 2 is independent of Question 1. If you know that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ and that there is a surjective map $\phi : \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Q}$ then you will easily find an answer.

Comment: @supinf For Q1, I have tried to gain intuition with the finite case (which seems to be standard, by Vandermonde determinant itself). But the infinite dimensional part throws me off. I have considered $x_n = 1 - b^n$ for $b \in (0,1)$ but it's not it.

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek I have edited my question in response to your comment, which wasn't clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: This answer addresses an earlier version of the question.

The answer to Q1 is **no**: If there is $a,x\in (0,1)^{\mathbb N}$ such that
$$
\sum a_n = \nu_0, \ \sum a_nx_n = \nu_1
$$
then this implies $\nu_1<\nu_0$ if $a\ne0$: Since $x_n\in(0,1)$, it holds for all $a_n>0$: $a_nx_n < a_n$. Summing up, yields $\nu_1<\nu_0$.

Comment: I have updated the question, based on the underlying problem, to avoid this easy answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Would have been better to post a new question than to edit the question such that answers are not valid anymore.